# how to find a descendant with highest value in xml actionscript

Tags: xml, actionscript

ok so in actionscript using xml I can find all the nodes of the same name using

```
xmlList.descendants("nodename");
```

and that returns me a XMLlist of those nodes that exist within the xmlList I provided all well and good but now I want to only get the one node of the returned value that has the largest value.

So the question is this. Do I have to loop through the resulting nodes or can I get that node without a loop maybe some other xmllist function I'm not aware of ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this instead of a loop:

```
var xml:XML = 
<xml>
    <element id="1" value="22" />
    <element id="2" value="33" />
    <element id="3" value="11" />
</xml>;

var max:Number = Number.MIN_VALUE;
xml.element.(max = Math.max(max, @value));
var top:XMLList = xml.element.(@value == max);
```

To be honest, I sometimes have a hard time getting my head around how these kinds of E4X expressions work, but they do.

Comment: what if the value value is just contained in the xml element like
<xml>
    <element>22<element>
 <element>33<element>
 <element>11<element>
</xml>;

Comment: Then I guess you could use valueOf(), so something like xml.element.(max = Math.max(max, valueOf()));
var top:XMLList = xml.element.(valueOf() == max);

Answer (score 0):

With this xml:

```
var data:XML = <items>  
         <item name="Wii">   
             <price>364.00</price>  
         </item>  
         <item name="Wii">   
             <price>249.99</price>  
         </item>  
         <item name="X-Box 360">    
             <price>399.99</price>  
         </item>  
         <item name="PlayStation 3">  
             <price>599.99</price>  
        </item>  
</items>;

var filter:XMLList = data.item.(price > 300);
            trace(filter);
```

You will get an output of:

```
<item name="Wii">
  <source>Amazon</source>
  <price>364.00</price>
</item>
<item name="X-Box 360">
  <source>Amazon</source>
  <price>399.99</price>
</item>
<item name="PlayStation 3">
  <source>Amazon</source>
  <price>599.99</price>
</item>
```

I think this is the closest you could get with getting numbers,and there is no a way you can get a max/min value straight from XML (you probably need to create some functions) you can read an implementation of it here :
[MinMaxXML](http://www.frankgarofalo.com/blog/posts/?pid=87)